# Single Page Application: Disable fast back from Browser?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, caching

I have single page application(Rails if it matters), where I am struggling with Browser cache. When user press back button *It loads page from cache, not even HTTP 304*. I have already set *no-cache* in response, but I belive browser has another layer of cache on top for single page application to provide fast back.

I understand there are some solutions here:-

1. [Disable browser back button for one page application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31308958/disable-browser-back-button-for-one-page-application)
2. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/256363/dealing-with-browser-cache-in-single-page-apps

However all of them involve, having either a popup box, or disabling back button. Both I think are terrible UX choices. Is there any other way to force browser to query server in SPA?

Comment: Are you using `turbolinks`?

Comment: Just checked, I am. I was using an older gemfile. So removing it should solve the issue?

Comment: Might be worth a shot. Hard to say exactly what's going on without code and an example.

Comment: Sorry I will add all later I thouhgt it might not be relevant to server at all

Comment: Also, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744169/rails-set-no-cache-method-cannot-disable-browser-caching-in-safari-and-opera#15565506

Comment: I did the same. Added no-cache etc in the controller to send in response. I can see them set in response in the browser inpect window. The problem is that Browser is not even giving HTTP304, i.e. it is not even returning page from cache. There is simply no call in networks tab